# UFW won't start at boot

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, ufw

I've got a little problem with ufw on Raspbian (Debian) on my Raspberry Pi 4 B. I have it as a server with public IP. It looks like it works like it should, but after reboot the ufw is inactive.
I've isolated some kind of problem in

`/lib/systemd/system/ufw.service`

I've changed ExecStart and ExecStop, so file looks like this

```
[Unit]
Description=Uncomplicated firewall
Documentation=man:ufw(8)
DefaultDependencies=no
-Before=network.target
+After=network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=ufw enable
ExecStop=ufw disable

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

So it works now at boot, but I know, that it's not the right solution. It's temporary solution, so it'll work till I fix it. I reboot a lot and I can have power outage at my home, so it can "reboot" without me knowing it with firewall turned off.

Have you any ideas, please?

Comment: Could you edit and add the results of `$ systemctl status ufw.service`